# Como utilizar o método setTimeout() para retardar o aparecimento de um alert em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert, settimeout

Boa tarde, neste momento estou a desenvolver um projeto de javascript, html e css. trata-se do jogo do Galo, o jogo funciona só que necessito que o alert de vitória ou de empate só apareça depois de o X ou a O. E o que está a acontecer é que o alert aparece 1º que a imagem. Depois de pesquisar encontrei  o método setTimeout(), mas não estou a perceber como utilizar.

Vou colocar todo o código que tenho até agora.

Muito obrigado

```js
var jogador = 'X';
var empate = 0;


function vJogo (id){
 var src = vSrc(id);
 var pc = document.getElementById('pc').checked;
 

 if (src=="branco.jpg") {
  document.getElementById(id).src="images/" + jogador + ".jpg";

  empate++;

 if (vencedor()){
  alert("Fim do jogo! Parabéns !!!  Venceu o "+ jogador );
 
 
  return;
 } 

 if(empate >= 9){
 alert("Empate !!!");

 
 return;

}



  if (jogador =='X') {
   jogador = 'O';
  }else{
   jogador = 'X';
  }
 }
 if(pc && jogador == 'O'){
  vJogo(computadorJoga());
 }
}
function computadorJoga(){
 if (vSrc('cel4')=='branco.jpg') {
  return 'cel4' ;
 }
 
 return 'cel' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1);

}
function vSrc(id){
 var src = document.getElementById(id).src;
 return src.substring(src.length -10, src.length);
} 
function vencedor (){
 if ((vSrc('cel0')==vSrc('cel1')) && (vSrc('cel0')== vSrc('cel2')) && vSrc('cel0') !='branco.jpg') {
  return true;
 }
 if ((vSrc('cel3')==vSrc('cel4')) && (vSrc('cel3')== vSrc('cel5')) && vSrc('cel3') !='branco.jpg') {
  return true;
 }
 if ((vSrc('cel6')==vSrc('cel7')) && (vSrc('cel6')== vSrc('cel8')) && vSrc('cel6') !='branco.jpg') {
  return true;
 }
 if ((vSrc('cel0')==vSrc('cel3')) && (vSrc('cel0')== vSrc('cel6')) && vSrc('cel0') !='branco.jpg') {
  return true;
 }
 if ((vSrc('cel1')==vSrc('cel4')) && (vSrc('cel1')== vSrc('cel7')) && vSrc('cel1') !='branco.jpg') {
  return true;
 }
 if ((vSrc('cel2')==vSrc('cel5')) && (vSrc('cel2')== vSrc('cel8')) && vSrc('cel2') !='branco.jpg') {
  return true;
 }
 if ((vSrc('cel0')==vSrc('cel4')) && (vSrc('cel0')== vSrc('cel8')) && vSrc('cel0') !='branco.jpg') {
  return true;
 }
 if ((vSrc('cel2')==vSrc('cel4')) && (vSrc('cel2')== vSrc('cel6')) && vSrc('cel2') !='branco.jpg') {
  return true;
 }
 
 
 return false;
}



function novoJogo(){
 location.reload();
}
```

```css
body{
 background:silver;
}
h1{
 font-size:40px;
 color: bold;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 3px 4px 3px red;
}
h3{
 color: bold;
}
table{
 width: 450px;
 height:300px;
 border:2px solid red;
 border-spacing: 5px;
 margin:auto;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px silver;

}
table tr { 
 background-color: silver;
 
 
}
table tr td {
  text-align:center; 
  width:33.33%}


img {
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 17px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
}  
 input{
  border-color: red;
  margin-left: 200px;
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funcao.js"></script>
 <title>Jogo do Galo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <h1>Jogo do Galo</h1>
 <h3>Computador</h3>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="pc" >
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td ><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel0" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td>   
   <td><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel1" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td>
   <td><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel2" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td ><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel3" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td>
   <td><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel4" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td>
   <td ><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel5" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td ><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel6" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td>
   <td ><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel7" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td>
   <td ><img src="images/branco.jpg" id="cel8" onclick="vJogo(this.id)"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="button" value="NOVO JOGO" name="botao"  id="botao" onclick="novoJogo()">
</div >
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma: defina uma função em que você fará o `alert()`.

```
function minhaFuncao() {
    alert('Chegou aqui.');
}
```

Agora, você pode chamar a função `setTimeout` passando como primeiro parâmetro uma função a ser executada e como segundo parâmetro o tempo que deve esperar para chamar essa função em milissegundos.

```
setTimeout(minhaFuncao, 4000);
```

No exemplo acima, a função `minhaFuncao` será executada após 4 segundos.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Phelipe, já funcionou.